# Basic C++ object class

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, object

I have implemented a basic `object` class in C++, and I want to make sure that I have implemented everything *efficiently and safely*, as I made a few mistakes while making it, which I corrected, but I could have left a few more mistakes behind:

```
class object
{
private:
    class dummy
    {
    public:
        dummy()
        {
        }
        virtual ~dummy()
        {
        }
        virtual const std::type_info &type() = 0;
        virtual dummy *duplicate() const = 0;
        virtual bool eq(object &) = 0;
    };

    template < typename _Ty > class data : public dummy
    {
    public:
        data()
        {
        }

        data(const _Ty &_Value)
            : __data(_Value)
        {
        }

        ~data()
        {
        }

        const std::type_info &type()
        {
            return typeid(_Ty);
        }

        data *duplicate() const
        {
            return new data<_Ty>(__data);
        }

        bool eq(object &_Obj)
        {
            return _Obj.cast<_Ty>() == __data;
        }

        _Ty __data;
    };

    dummy *d;
public:
    object()
    {
    }

    template < typename _Ty > object(const _Ty &_Value)
        : d(new data<_Ty>(_Value))
    {
    }

    object(const object &_Obj)
        : d(_Obj.d->duplicate())
    {
    }

    ~object()
    {
        if (!empty())
        {
            delete d;
        }
    }

    const std::type_info &type()
    {
        return (empty() ? typeid(void) : d->type());
    }

    object &operator=(object &_Rhs)
    {
        d = _Rhs.d->duplicate();
        return *this;
    }

    object &swap(object &_Rhs)
    {
        std::swap(*this, _Rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    template < typename _Ty > object &operator=(const _Ty &_Value)
    {
        d = new data<_Ty>(_Value);
        return *this;
    }

    template < typename _Ty > _Ty cast()
    {
        if (type() == typeid(_Ty))
        {
            return static_cast<data<_Ty> *>(d)->__data;
        }
        throw std::exception("Invalid cast type");
    }

    bool operator==(object &_Rhs)
    {
        return (type() == _Rhs.d->type() ? d->eq(_Rhs) : false);
    }

    template < typename _Ty > bool operator==(_Ty _Value)
    {
        return (type() == typeid(_Ty) ? cast<_Ty>() == _Value : false);
    }

    bool operator!=(object &_Rhs)
    {
        return !(*this == _Rhs);
    }

    template < typename _Ty > bool operator!=(const _Ty &_Value)
    {
        return !(*this == _Value);
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return !d;
    }
};
```

Comment: 1) Replace `{ }` with `= default;` 2) Get rid of names starting with underscore(s)

Comment: You should stop using reserved identifiers.

Comment: Your default constructor `object(){}` will *default-initialize* the data member `dummy *d;`. Default-initialization for fundamental types means **no initialization is performed**. Subsequent calls of `empty()` might return `false`. Use value-initialization `object() : d() {}` or explicit initialization `object() : d(nullptr) {}`. Also, you don't need to check `if(!empty())` before `delete d;`; deleting a nullptr value is safe.

Comment: `std::swap(*this, _Rhs);` won't do any magic. It will make a three copies (one copy-construction of a "temporary", and two copy-assignments). That's exactly what you want to *avoid* when supplying a custom `swap` function. Also, you should consider making it a non-member friend function, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695855/420683

Comment: Why!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
object &operator=(object &_Rhs)
{
    d = _Rhs.d->duplicate();
    return *this;
}
```

I think you're leaking your previous `d` object.

It's also conventional to verify whether `_Rhs` and `this` are the same (and to do nothing if they are), otherwise it will misbehave if you assign an object to itself (like `foo = foo;`).

Comment: Or to use copy-and-swap instead.

Answer (score 7):

- As per common naming convention, the class names should start with a capital letter.
- It may be more readable to put the `template` line above the `class` line:

  ```
  template < typename _Ty >
  class data : public dummy
  {
  }
  ```
- Your `bool` functions should be `const`.  Any member function that doesn't modify data members should be `const`.  Such functions also include accessors ("getters") and the `bool` operators (`operator==`, `operator!=`, `operator<`, and `operator>`).

  For instance, with `empty()`:

  ```
  bool empty() const
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  and `operator==`:

  ```
  bool operator==(object &_Rhs) const
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  Also, the above parameter should be `const&` since `_Rhs` is not being modified.
- If you're not defining your own constructor and/or destructor, you don't need to make them yourself.  The compiler will make them for you.

  However, if you're using C++11, you can have an [explicitly defaulted constructor and destructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions):

  ```
  data() = default;
  ~data() = default;
  ```

Comment: A default constructor will be created for you if no other constructor exists. I think it's always clearer to use `default` for this reason - it shows *intent* to have a default constructor.

Comment: @Yuushi: Oh, you mean like `data() = default;`?  If I'm correct, it's for C++11.

Comment: "As per common naming convention, the class names should start with a capital letter." Like the standard library?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Stroustrup suggests that you capitalize user-defined names in TC++PLv4p156. He then continues, "Note that the language and the standard library use lowercase for types; this can be seen as a hint that they are part of the standard."

Comment: @Jamal - the only point I disagree with in your answer is this: "As per common naming convention, the class names should start with a capital letter". In all C++ projects I've worked in, the naming convention was never based on Stroustrup's suggestion; instead, it was either MFC/hungarian convention (yuk!), or `lower_case_with_underscores` because of uniformity of client code and readability (or similar arguments), or a custom convention (e.g. `int mylib_ApiName(const int in_value, int &out_value);` or similar).